# Graph Theory: Graph with bipartite subgraph has MORE than e(G)/2 edges.

Tags: graph-theory, induction

Show that every loopless graph G has a bipartite subgraph with more than e(G)/2 edges. Use induction on the number of vertices.

Clearly if n(G) = 2, the hypothesis holds. But I am not sure how to formulate the induction step.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: The strict inequality is actually false for the graph with two vertices and no edges; in all other cases, however, it holds.

Suppose that every graph with $n$ vertices has the desired property, and let $G$ be a graph with $n+1$ vertices. Let $v$ be any vertex of $G$, and let $G'$ be the subgraph of $G$ that remains after you remove $v$ and the edges incident at $v$. $G'$ has $n$ vertices, so either it has a bipartite subgraph $H$ with more than $\frac12e(G')$ edges, or $n=2$ and $G'=H$ has no edges.

Let $A$ and $B$ be the parts of $H$, and let $W$ be the set of vertices in $G'$ that are joined to $v$ by an edge of $G$. Without loss of generality $|W\cap A|\ge|W\cap B|$.

- To which of $A$ and $B$ should you add $v$, and which edges at $v$ should you keep, in order to expand $H$ to a bipartite subgraph of $G$ with more than $\frac12e(G)$ edges?

Answer that question and fill in the details of the argument, and you’ll have your induction step.

Comment: I am not sure about that... If you add v to B and keep the edges which already had one endpoint in B, would that give you over half the edges of G in B?

Comment: @PhiB: If you add $V$ to $B$ and keep the edges in $H$ and the edges from $v$ to $A$, you’ll have a bipartite graph with more than $\frac12e(G)$ edges.

Comment: Oh, OK! I totally see that now. Thank you.

Comment: @PhiB: You’re welcome.

Comment: I need one bit of clarification: when we say "...either it has a bipartite subgraph H with more than 1/2 e(H) edges, ...", don't we really mean 1/2 e(G') edges? H has all of H's edges.

Comment: @PhiB: Yes, that was a typo; I’ve fixed it now.

Comment: No problem. Thanks.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott i am not getting how $\left | W\cap A \right |\geq \left | W\cap B \right |$ is coming ...!! can you please explain?

Comment: @sourav: $H$ has two parts. One of them contains at least half of the vertices in $W$; we’ll call that part $A$ and the other one $B$, so that $|W\cap A|\ge|W\cap B|$. In other words, we simply choose the labels $A$ and $B$ to make it true.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott thank you for your answer ...i have one more doubt  ..i am stuck at this question ...http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2011664/number-of-edges-and-degree-in-a-simple-graph i  know it is not right to ask question this way ..but i have no option left ... as no one is helping me ..can you please answer the question !!

Comment: @sourav: I’ve a few things to do first, but I’ll take a look sometime this afternoon.

Comment: sure ... thank you very much for your consideration !!!@BrianM.Scott