# Number of edges and degree in a simple graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, proof-explanation

For a Simple Graph G with vertices $v_{1},v_{2},.....,v_{n}$  ,  $n  \geq 3$

Given **Proposition**   $\Rightarrow$

$e \left(G \right)$=$\frac{\sum e \left(G -v_{i}\right)}{n-2}$

and

$d_{G} \left(v_{i} \right)$=$\frac{\sum e \left(G -v_{i}\right)}{n-2} - e \left (G-v_{j} \right) $

Explanation -:

An edge of $G$ appears in $G-v_{i}$ if and only if v_{i} is not endpoint of e.(i got this point ). Thus $ \sum \left (G-v_{i} \right )$ counts each edge exactly $n-2$ times.

i am not getting this point and so is the 1st equation.

Furthur  its explained that  **once we know $e \left(G \right)$ ,the degree of $v_{i}$   can be computed as the number of edges lost when deleting $ v _{i}$  to form $G -v_{j}$ and hence 2nd eqtn proved .....not getting this too..**

Comment: Any0ne please help me out ...!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose for a moment that we know that

$$e(G)=\frac{\sum_ie(G-v_i)}{n-2}\;.\tag{1}$$

There are $e(G)$ edges in $G$. Removing $v_j$ from $G$ removes only the edges of $G$ that have $v_j$ as an endpoint, and there are $\deg_G(v_j)$ of those. Thus, the number of edges in $G-v_j$ must be $e(G)-\deg_G(v_j)$, i.e., $e(G-v_j)=e(G)-\deg_G(v_j)$. Rearranging this and substituting the known value of $e(G)$ from $(1)$ gives us the result that

$$\deg_G(v_j)=e(G)-e(G-v_j)=\frac{\sum_ie(G-v_i)}{n-2}-e(G-v_j)\;.$$

Now let’s get back to $(1)$. For each vertex $v_i$ of $G$ we know that $e(G-v_i)=e(G)-\deg_G(v_i)$, so

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^ne(G-v_i)&=\sum_{i=1}^n\big(e(G)-\deg_G(v_i)\big)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^ne(G)-\sum_{i=1}^n\deg_G(v_i)\\
&=ne(G)-\sum_{i=1}^n\deg_G(v_i)\\
&=ne(G)-2e(G)\\
&=(n-2)e(G)\;,
\end{align*}$$

and $(1)$ follows immediately

Comment: Perfect Explanation .....thank you once again  :) @ :Brian

Comment: @sourav: You’re welcome!

Comment: @:Brian sir how can i communicate you ...so that i can ask my question/doubt as i am learning graph theory and i love solving it !!! it would be a great help for me if you please find a solution for it  ..thank you :)

Comment: @:Brian sir can you please help me out in this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2013683/the-union-of-edge-sets-of-distinct-u-v-path-must-contain-a-cycle ....Please !!!

Comment: @sourav: I’ll take a look later today when I get back from a dental appointment.

Comment: okk no problem sir ..have a look when you have time  :) !!! thank you

Comment: sir please look into this problem .. i need your help @:Brian sir  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2024129/decomposition-of-complete-graph-k-n-into-cycles-when-n-9