# In simple graph, union of Edge sets of distinct u−v Path must contain a cycle. T/F

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

In this question  [The union of Edge sets of distinct $u - v $ Path must contain a cycle.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2013683/the-union-of-edge-sets-of-distinct-u-v-path-must-contain-a-cycle) the solution shows that for base case of induction we need a multi-graph. But if it is clearly mentioned that the graph is simple, does it suffice to say that a single edge graph u-v doesn't have a cycle in the union of edge sets? And hence the statement fails for simple graphs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a simple graph the base case is vacuously true: *there are never two **distinct** $u-v$ paths whose lengths sum to $2$*. From there you can use the same induction argument.

The statement is still true for simple graphs, because every simple graph is also a multigraph that just happens to have at most $1$ edge between each pair of vertices.

Comment: If I take the graph as a single edge u--v then how is the statement valid in this case?

Comment: In that case, there is only one possible $u-v$ path. So there cannot be distinct paths in the first place. So the fact that there is no cycle doesn't matter, because there's also no distinct paths to take a union of.

Comment: Ok. Got it thanks!